# Uso de This en instancia de objeto

Tags: c#

Estoy siguiendo un curso de C# y me he encontrado con esto.

```
mantcamions mancamionsgrid = (mantcamions)this._ewMante;
```

¿Alguien me puede aclarar el uso de `this` en este contexto por favor?

Comment: El curso de c# se desarrolla con Forms en Visual Studio ?

Comment: Puedes añadir el código completo de lo que estás haciendo? 
La palabra this hace referencia a la instancia que estas usando. Revisate la [documentación de microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) donde te expone varios ejemplos.

Comment: `this` es la referencia al objeto actual.

Comment: Podrias poner algo mas de codigo donde se encuentra ubicada esa linea? porque el uso de this cambia segun el contexto

Answer (score 0):

La palabra reserva "this" se utiliza para referirte a la classe/objeto actual.

```
class mantcamions {

    public mantcamions() { }

    public void DoSomething() { }
}

static class Program() {

    object _ewMante = new mantcamions();

    public static Main(args...)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.Scope();
    }

    public void Scope() 
    {
        // this._ewMante.DoSomething(); No puedo hacer esto pq no es del tipo mantcamions sino de object
        // Cojo el objeto guardado en Main y le hago un "cast" a mantcamions para  poder utilizar sus propiedades y funciones
        mantcamions mancamionsgrid = (mantcamions)this._ewMante
        // Ahora si puedo
        mancamionsgrid.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias RubenGlam, no había contemplado la opción de que fuera un cast.

Comment: La palabra clave this no se puede usar en métodos estáticos, de lo contrario dará el error CS0026. En tu ejemplo, el "this" está innecesario. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0026

Comment: no puedes usar this dentro de Main siendo este `static`, quizas si lo pondrias dentro de `DoSomething()` eso seria diferente

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de aprender es leyendo primero la documentacion oficial

[this (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

alli comenta

> La palabra clave this hace referencia a la instancia actual de la clase y también se usa como modificador del primer parámetro de un método de extensión